# Reset android preferences after sim changed

Tags: android, validation

I want to cllear all preferences if the sim card has been changed. Actually I have a boot receiver that verifies if the sim id is the stored one but sometimes the method getSubscriberId is not available on boot_completed.
Any idea?

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps you should try [Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

On a reboot, simply update a persistent flag (e.g., a value in a different `SharedPreferences`) to indicate that you want to check the SIM. Then, check the SIM when your app next runs.

Or, skip the `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver, and just check the SIM when your app runs. Not all devices require a reboot to switch SIM cards.